# What determines the prefix used when you set a relative path in javascript parent.location

Tags: javascript, location, relative-url

I am working on a C# MVC website, and have a popup that redirects its parent with a window.parent.location=newRelativePath statement in JavaScript (and then calls a custom method to hide the popup).

In one place in my application, the redirection works great. The browser adds the correct protocol, host and domain at the start of the relative URL that I pass in, and navigates correctly. In another place in my application, the EXACT SAME CALL (i.e. newRelativePath is the same, being called from a popup, parent window has a URL that follows the same kind of format) doesn't work because the browser not only adds the protocol, host and domain, but also adds the controller name from the path of the prior page at the start of the URL (I get a 404 error saying the url "/domain/oldcontroller/newcontroller/action" cannot be found)

In both cases, my original parent window URL is in the format "protocol://host/domain/controller/action/id?querystring", and newRelativePath is in the format "controller/action?querystring"

I don't see any difference in the format of window.location or window.parent.location at the different spots in the application, but something must be different since the browser treats the relative URL I feed in differently - any ideas what that might be?

Thanks very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using something like this:

```
newcontroller/action
```

You have to use this:

```
/newcontroller/action
```

The slash `/` at the beginning is important to tell the explorer is not a relative path, but an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I did try that, but that omits the domain. Of course I could pass in the full path including the domain, but that's not ideal since I'd have to start to pass that path prefix into a method in a shared js file in many places throughout my application that are currently working okay with the relative URL. I'd much rather figure out why the spots differ and use a relative URL.